# "Dynamically" Generate a WPF View C# for Plotting with DynamicDataDisplay

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic-data-display

I am writing a WPF application in C#. This application is design using MVVM.

Currently, I have a parent window with a few check boxes. Use user can check whichever boxes they want and then click the "plot" `Button`. Once they click "plot", a new child window comes up displaying the data on a *single* graph.

So, if I have only 1 check box checked, and then click "plot", I will see a graph with a single line on it. If I have 2 check boxes check and click "plot", I will see the same single graph, but it will have 2 lines on it.

**My current Implementation:**

Currently, I have a "view" class called `GraphWindowView`. The view obviously needs to know of which data to show. So to do that, I have dependency properties `GraphWindowView.Dates` and `GraphWindowView.Data` which ultimatley produces a graph of `Data` (y axis) vs. `Dates` (x axis).

**Question:** This current implementation of `GraphWindowView` is obviously restricted to only being able to graph one set of data (i.e. `Data` vs. `Dates`). I would like to make this (a lot) more extensible and have an arbitrary number of plots available depending on how much check boxes are checked. How would I go about doing this? I think I need to rethink my use of dependency properties...

**>>> UPDATE**

So I made a `GraphLine` class which should represent a line on the graph. The "graph" is actually a `ChartPlotter` element in the `GraphWindowPresenter.xaml` class. Additionally, I specified a `DataType` for the `GraphLine` objects, but that is all I understand. What are the next steps to this, how do I actually add the data to the graph? And how/where do I make instances of `GraphLine` to populate the `ChartPlotter` element? Sorry I am pretty lost on this, even after reading quite a few tutorials. Thanks for all the help so far, I really appreciate it!

*GraphWindowView.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="BMSVM_Simulator.View.GraphWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:BMSVM_Simulator.ViewModel"
        xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
        x:Name="ThisGraphWindowInstance"
        Title="Plot" Height="500" Width="750"
        Icon="../res/qualcomm_q_icon.ico.ico"
        MinWidth="400" MinHeight="300">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:GraphWindowPresenter/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter" Margin="10,10,20,10">
        <d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
            <d3:HorizontalIntegerAxis Name="dateAxis"/>
        </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
        <d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>
            <d3:VerticalIntegerAxis Name="countAxis"/>
        </d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>

        <d3:Header FontFamily="Arial" Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisGraphWindowInstance, Path=title}"/>
        <d3:VerticalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial" Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisGraphWindowInstance, Path=yAxis}"/>
        <d3:HorizontalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial" Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisGraphWindowInstance, Path=xAxis}"/>
    </d3:ChartPlotter>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:GraphLine}">
            <!--WHAT GOES HERE-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

</Window>
```

*GraphLine.cs*

```
namespace BMSVM_Simulator.ViewModel
    {
        class GraphLine
        {
            public string xAxis                     { get; private set; }
            public string yAxis                     { get; private set; }
            public string title                     { get; private set; }
            public string legend                    { get; private set; }
            public EnumerableDataSource<int> data   { get; private set; }
            public EnumerableDataSource<int> dates  { get; private set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these types of problems in WPF can be sorted out by some careful use of data binding and `DataTemplate`s, rather than miles of procedural code. The general idea is that you create a custom class with all of the properties that are required to draw all of your lines. You would then declare a `DataTemplate` to define how the various properties are to be data bound, perhaps a little something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXamlNamespacePrefix:GraphLine}">
    <Line X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you create a collection of your custom class instances and data bind it to some collection control, like an `ItemsControl` and each one will be automatically rendered in the correct location:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourGraphLineCollection, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourXamlNamespacePrefix:YourControlName}}}" />
```

Welcome to the powerful world of WPF data binding and `DataTemplate`s.

---

UPDATE >>>

The custom class to data bind to the `Line` elements is not a view model. Think of it as a data type class, for which you will declare a `DataTemplate` like the one above. When I said that it should have all of the required properties, if you look at the above example, you'll see that it would at least need four `double` properties to data bind to the four used properties of the `Line` element. However, you might also choose to add further properties to data bind to the `Stroke`, `StrokeThickness` or `Fill` properties for example.

As for where you should define the `DataTemplate`, it should be within scope of the items that have it applied. If you want to use it in one view, then put it in the `UserControl.Resources` section of that view. However, if you want to use the same `DataTemplate`, then you should put it into the `Application.Resources` section of the `App.xaml` file because those `Resources` are available application wide.

---

FINAL UPDATE >>>

As noted in my comment, teaching users how to use WPF is definitely out of scope for this website, so I won't be doing that. To learn about `DataTemplate`s, you should read the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. When you don't know about something, MSDN should *always* be your first place to search for answers.

I can give you a few last tips before I go: The `DependencyProperty` in your control should be of type `ObservableCollection<GraphLine>`. Inside your control, you should data bind them to some sort of `ItemsControl` as shown above - I changed the `Binding Path` in it because you should really use a `RelativeSource Binding` to locate the property in your situation (where `YourControlName` is the name of your `UserControl` where you want to draw the `Line` objects).

Finally, in your view model (that is linked with the view that contains your new `UserControl` that draws the lines), you'll need a collection property to data bind with the collection in the `UserControl`, let's say named `YourGraphLineCollectionInViewModel`:

```
<YourXamlNamespacePrefix:YourControlName YourGraphLineCollection="{Binding 
    YourGraphLineCollectionInViewModel}" />
```

It's in this view model that you add the instances of your `GraphLine` class into the `YourGraphLineCollectionInViewModel` collection and as long as you have set up your `Binding Path`s as shown here, they'll appear in your UI within the `ItemsControl`. I am assuming that you know how to correctly set your `DataContext` - if not, you can easily find out how to do that online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just read a long tutorial on DataTemplates and now I'm trying to understand this approach. When you say I "create a custom class with all the properties required to draw on of your lines" do you mean like a `ViewModel` for my `GraphWindowView` class? Additionally, would the DataTemplate be defined (using .xaml) in my `GraphWindowView.xaml` class or my `MainWindowView.xaml` class? I think I understand the general use of DataTemplates, just not in my specific context/scenario.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the help so far, I've updated my orignal post and I'm getting there, if you could respond to that it would be awesome. Thanks so much for the help so far!

Comment: I've got to be honest... answering these types of questions, where a user keeps adding new requirements and dragging them on and on are quite annoying. In future, please put *all* of your requirements into your question *in the beginning*. It is *not* the job of Stack Overflow answer authors to teach how to use a particular language... questions are *supposed* to have a narrow focus, like 'Can anyone see a bug in this code?', rather than 'Can anyone teach me how to do something?' The reason is simple... the internet is full of tutorials for learning from... this site is not.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I've read tutorials and I do not understand them in the context of my code. You answers shed a lot of light on the subject, though. Thanks again.